# Ubuntu customization kit, not opening gnome-terminal, help please!

Tags: gnome-terminal, unicode, uck

I've been trying to solve this for 3 days,
I'm using Ubuntu Customization Kit and when it gets to "Run console application" I get the following error:

```
Starting console application...
Option "-t" is no longer supported in this version of gnome-terminal.
Error constructing proxy for org.gnome.Terminal:/org/gnome/Terminal/
Factory0: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gnome.Terminal:
GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process
org.gnome.Terminal exited with status 8
```

I read online that this is due to not having unicode set for gnome-terminal, however I need to set it for the gnome-terminal that's located inside the temp ISO image that UCK creates. I tried copying etc/locale.conf and etc/default/locale into the image, but it has no effect, probably as it should be restarted, which I have no way to do. Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
 CONSOLE_APP=`which gnome-terminal`
    CONSOLE_APP_OPTIONS=(-T "UCK customization console" -e /bin/bash)
```

TO

```
CONSOLE_APP=`which xterm`
    CONSOLE_APP_OPTIONS=(-e /bin/bash)
```

in /usr/lib/uck/customization-profiles/localized_cd/customize
.
Works for me.